# Is any continous map $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau_u) \to (\mathbb{R},\tau_u)$ either open or closed?

Tags: general-topology

Is any continous map $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau_u) \to (\mathbb{R},\tau_u)$ either open or closed?
I suddenly came up with a counterexample by defining $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

one can note that $$f\big((-1,1)\big)=\left(\frac12,1\right]$$ wheareas 
$$f\big([1,\infty)\big)=\left(0,\frac12\right].$$

Is it correct/enough?

Now I wonder under what conditions a continous map $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau_u) \to (\mathbb{R},\tau_u)$  is either closed or open?

Will it work if I restrict my domain? that is If $f:([a,b],\tau_u) \to (\mathbb{R},\tau_u)$

What If I want to consider the maps $f:(X,\tau) \to (Y,\tau')$  ? Under what conditions a continous map is either open or closed?

Comment: What is $\tau_u$?

Comment: The map will be open (or closed)  iff the _inverse_ is continuous (in case there is an inverse).

Comment: @ChrisCuster the map is neither onto nor 1-1.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I see that.  Indeed, it is not.  But in general... one could construct a counterexample if one could find a bijection which is continuous,  but not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail please how you *suddenly* came up with an example? Assuming $\tau_u$ is the usual topology, every continuous map $f:([a,b],\tau_u) \to (\mathbb{R},\tau_u)$ is closed. This is a special case of the more general result that if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is closed. Indeed, every closed $C\subseteq X$ will be compact, hence $f(C)$ is compact (by continuity), hence $f(C)$ is closed (using that $Y$ is $T_2$). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps#Open_and_closed_mapping_theorems

Comment: @Mirko I will love to answer that. I knew that $f(x)=x^2$ is not an open map, as it sends $(-1,1)$ to $[0,1)$. Now I was in need of a map that sends closed sets to 'not closed' sets. $\frac{1}{x}$ instantly comes into mind when we let $x \to \infty$. So I combined both of them. that gave me $\frac{1}{x^2}$, but wait it is not continous at $x=0$. So I tried $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ which worked very well..